# Check for an empty Text Box

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a text box in a Word 2016 document.  This is not a TextBox form object but a normal Text Box that you insert from the Insert tab here:

[image: Insert Menu]

I am trying to check if it is empty when the document is opened.  For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.  I have tried all of the following:

```
If (Len(ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbNullString) = 0) Then
If (IsNull(ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text)) Then
If (LTrim(RTrim(ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text)) = "") Then
If (ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "") Then
```

None of these return true when the text box is empty?  This is the text box:

[image: Text Box]

It seems that the text box always contains a paragraph marker (which I can't delete).  This is what the VBA watch shows:

```
Watch :   : ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text : "
" : String : ThisDocument.Document_Open
```

Note that the watch is two separate lines which makes me think that there's CRLF or something in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a paragraph break in an otherwise empty textbox. Accordingly, you could use something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes("Text Box 2")
    If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
      If Trim(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) = vbCr Then
        MsgBox "Empty Text Range"
      End If
    Else
      MsgBox "No Text Range"
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```